# using a box layout in java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

the following codes created a box layout conviniently but the problem i have is the textfields occupy the entire rows. which is supposed to asume the parameter length in which it was specified.

```
 public void makeControlpanel(){
    JPanel controlpanel = new JPanel();
     //SET PANEL LAYOUT MANAGERS
    controlpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(controlpanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    controlpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Create Control file")); 


    filenameC   = new JLabel("Filename");
    filenameBad   = new JLabel("Bad Filename");
    filenameDis = new JLabel("Discard Filename");

    // fields
    fileField = new JTextField(1);
    badfileField = new JTextField(7);
    discardfileField = new JTextField(7);
```

Comment: Have you read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html ? In general, layoutmanagers have the right to override such properties as the size of the components.

Comment: either use a LayoutManager that allows the fine-tuning you want or subclass JTextField to return a maxSize. The former is recommended, you'll need a more powerful LayoutManager anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The layout manager decides the size of the components. You have options to define the bounds of a component to the layout manager using

```
comp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w, h));
comp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
comp.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w, h));
```

When you give `setPreferredSize` layout manager will **try** to give that size. GridBagLayout is the msot flexible layout and you can prettymuch achieve any layout you need.

The parameter `length` by defenition only defines the character you can put in the textfield.

Comment: no - **never-ever** use any of the setXXSize methods for reasons see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657), instead use a suitable LayoutManager.

Comment: @ Kleopatra, what layout do u suggest,as i want to arrange the components i the panel in rows of different lenghts

Comment: @lee my personal favourite currently is MigLayout (btw: the space between the ampersand and the name prevents that I get notified of your comment :-)

Comment: @Kleopatra One should know that these methods exists and what it does so that he can decide whether to use it or not. @Lee Try `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: no, best to forget (or newbies never learn) that those methods exist - applying them leads to endless pain further down the route ..